# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll - Java Weblogic and C# application

Tags: java, c#, .net, windows, weblogic

I need help with this issue.

As I'm migrating a weblogic project from ant to Maven platform (using WSDL services) and consuming it from .Net C# client application, I have got some troubles. First, I do not have any idea what's going on when I try to consume the service because, when I update references in client side I get a file named as "Reference.cs" all the services are defined such as the following code:

```
public **abstract** partial class NameService: xmlObject {

    private int attributeName;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public int AtributeName{
        get {
            return this.attributeName;
        }
        set {
            this.attributeName= value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("AtributeName");
        }
    }
```

}

I'm not sure why services classes are defined as "abstract", so I changed them as only public classes to instantiate them in my customized classes, such as follows:

```
ServiceDefinitionPortTypeClient test= new ServiceDefinitionPortTypeClient ();
serviceNameRequestDocument sesReq = new serviceNameRequestDocument ();
serviceNameRequest req = new serviceNameRequest();
req.inServiceNameRequest = SetDataToReq();
sesReq.serviceNameRequest = req;
DigitemServices.serviceNameRequestDocument resp = test.serviceName(sesReq);
```

In SetDataReq() method I only set all the service fields with values.
So, when I execute this code I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

 - with linked exception:

[org.xml.sax.SAXException: 

Exception Description: The instance creation method [com.latam.xxx.xxx.serviceName.<Default Constructor>], with no parameters, does not exist, or is not accessible.

Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.latam.xxx.xxx.serviceName.<init>()

Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.latam.xxx.xxx.serviceName --> [DatabaseTable(ns0:serviceName)])

Exception [EclipseLink-63] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException

Exception Description: The instance creation method [com.latam.xxx.xxx.serviceName.<Default Constructor>], with no parameters, does not exist, or is not accessible.

Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.latam.xxx.xxx.serviceName.<init>()

Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.latam.xxx.xxx.serviceName --> [DatabaseTable(ns0:serviceName)])]
```

In server side I do not catch any log or warning/error.

I hope you can help me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should extend the abstract classes instead of modifying them. Abstract classes dont have constructers and cant be instantiated like you are trying to do. Thus the error: > The instance creation method [com.latam.xxx.xxx.serviceName.<Default Constructor>], with no parameters, does not exist, or is not accessible.

Comment: You're right, however I have a doubt. Before, when server was working in Ant platform, when I updated references in client side, the generated classes were not "abstract", and now with Maven the type is abstract. Do you have any idea why is it happenning?